# WPF event within a frame stored on a stackpanel

Tags: wpf, image, events, frames

I need to recreate a program similar to whatsapp that can send and receive messages, images videos and audio. I have created a WPF form to show messages that looks like this: 
[image: Image can be found here]

I have a stack panel that contains text bubbles on them. Text messages work fine but if I send an image I want the user to be able to click on the image text bubble and it must become full screen. The image text bubble consists of a label that has a frame in it and then within that frame the image is stored. The label was used since we could resize the label.

However, because the image is done like this dynamically, we cannot seem to register an on-click event on this image bubble. If you have any better ways that we can display the image or how to log this event it would be much appreciated. Here is the method used to add the image.

```
 public void AddMessage_Image(string path, string displayName, int role, string date = "")
    {
        //Create an image from the path
        ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush();
        image.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute));
        image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

        //Create a frame in which to place the image
        Frame fr = new Frame();
        fr.Background = image;
        fr.MinHeight = 120;
        fr.MinWidth = 160;

        //Ensure scalabilty of the image
        Viewbox vb = new Viewbox();
        vb.Child = fr;
        vb.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;

        //Place the image in a sizable container
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.MinHeight = 10;
        lbl.MinWidth = 10;
        lbl.MaxHeight = 300;
        lbl.MaxWidth = 400;
        lbl.Content = vb;

        if (role == (int) Role.Sender)
            lbl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        else
            lbl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;

        lbl.Background = Brushes.Black;

        //Place the image in the chat
        chatbox.Children.Add(lbl);
    }
```

Comment: Why can't you register for an event inside this method? And why do you assign the `Image` to a `Frame` and the `Frame` to a `ViewBox`and this `ViewBox` to a `Label` just to display the image? You can put an Image directly into a `ViewBox` and resize it. I think you don't need the `Frame` and the `LabeL`, do you?

Comment: `var viewBox = new ViewBox() { Child = image };
viewBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += ResizeImageToFullScreen;`   Then set `ViewBox.Height` and `ViewBox.Width` accordingly.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you very much

Comment: When the `Height` of a `ViewBox` is not set (`Auto`) then it will stretch to fit the `Window` size (or the maximum available size). So you just have to give it a `Height` and toggle between this height value and `Double.NAN` (`Auto`) : `viewBox.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += (sender, e) => (sender as FrameworkElement).Height = double.IsNaN(viewBox.Height) ? 180 : double.NaN;`

Comment: It's a lot easier to do it in XAML. If you'd know about templates than you can use a `ListView` to display the chat items (e.g. text, image, video). You'd then use `DataTemplate`  to automatically create the appropriate item container (e.g. a `TextBlock`, `ViewBox`, `MediaElement`). This is quite simple and straightforward. `EventTrigger` can trigger on mouse click and animate the `ViewBox` size.